# Probability not to cross diagonal in NxN grid

Tags: combinatorics

I have to calculate number of ways, which crosses the diagonal in 100x100 grid, moving only to the right and up.

I'm aware the number of ways not crossing diagonal is twice Catalan number.

However how to calculate the probability of opposite, P(crossing the diagonal)?

Also for me there is a problem to calculate the total amount if ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of ways to reach the upper-right corner of an $(m,n)$ grid by starting at the lower-left corner and only moving one unit up or one unit right each turn is just the binomial coefficient $\binom{m+n}{n}$.

Also,
$$P(\text{crossing the diagonal}) = 1 - P(\text{not crossing the diagonal})$$ Can you finish?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot!:)